# Vertical Split Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a layout that is split in two parts vertical . My App is always in landscape mode.

Please help.

I tried it with a tablelayout.

```
 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
 android:stretchColumns="*" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: i tried it with a tablelayout. But i can't make it. i should look like [ | ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `TableLayout`, so I'll try to explain you how to achieve this by using the `LinearLayout`. You need to set your layout's orientation to horizontal using `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Then you should create two `LinearLayouts` inside, both having `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. Then you can put anything inside these layouts, and the whole view will be split in two horizontal parts. Hope this helps!

Comment: And if you still want to work with TableLayout check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) tutorial, maybe you can adapt it to your app.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use Egor's solution but also nest everything inside a `RelativeLayout` just in case you would like to add a title in another `LinearLayout` (this way you can add a android:below on the other container)